# Values not getting reflected in UI . --> DJANGO

Tags: python, django, html-table, datatable

I am doing a Django program with a single UI containing two table, But the data is reflected only in one table of UI and not the other .

In Network  --> Response it prints both data

so here is my code :

**Views.py**

```
def secondtableonDashboard(request):
    Server_list = ""
    NewList = ""
    afterConcat = ""
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                          'Server=ABC\SQLEXPRESS;'
                          'Database=WebstartUI;'
                          'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from CustomerServer")
    result = cursor.fetchall()

    if request.method=='POST':
       user_list = request.POST.getlist('checked_list')
       Server_list = listToString(user_list) +","
    else:
       print("No Values")

    for listValue in Server_list.split(","):
        NewList = "'"+listValue+"',"
        afterConcat = afterConcat + NewList
    Server_list = afterConcat[:-5]
    Server_list = Server_list[1:]
    ServiceList = conn.cursor()
    cmd = "Select * from dbo.ServiceRunningStatus where ServerName IN ('"+Server_list+"')"
    ServiceList.execute(cmd)
    resultOfServiceList = ServiceList.fetchall()
    print(resultOfServiceList)

    return render(request,'side-menu-light-tabulator.html',{'customerserver':result,'ServerList':resultOfServiceList})
```

So here it prints the value of "resultOfServiceList" on my terminal

**side-menu-light-tabulator.html**

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th></th>
                                                        <th>ServerName</th>
                                                        <th>Customer Name</th>
                                                        <th>node Labels</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    {% for datas in customerserver %}
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                          <div class="form-check form-switch">
                                                            <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                                                                <input class="form-check-input" name="Servers[]" value="{{datas.ServerName}}" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
                                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
                                                            </form>
                                                          </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>{{datas.ServerName}}</td>
                                                        <td>{{datas.CustomerName}}</td>
                                                        <td>{{datas.NodeLabels}}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>

                                      <!-- </div> -->
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="source-code hidden">
                                      <div class="alert alert-danger-soft show flex items-center mb-2" role="alert"> <i data-feather="alert-octagon" class="w-6 h-6 mr-2"></i> Awesome alert with icon </div>
                                      <div class="overflow-y-auto mt-3 rounded-md">
                                          <table id="exampleSecond" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th></th>
                                                    <th>ServerName</th>
                                                    <th>Component</th>
                                                    <th>PID</th>
                                                    <th>State</th>
                                                    <th>Start</th>
                                                    <th>Stop</th>
                                                    <th>Restart</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                {% for serv in ServerList %}
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                      <div class="form-check form-switch">
                                                          <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                                                              <input class="form-check-input services" name="Service[]" value="{{serv.ServerName}}" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
                                                              <label class="form-check-label services" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
                                                          </form>
                                                      </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>{{serv.ServerName}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{serv.Component}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{serv.PID}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{serv.State}}</td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
```

Here first table is printing without any problems , but the second is only getting printed in console .

Comment: I don't really know but `<div class="source-code hidden">` here the class hidden looks like it hides the element by setting `display: none;` or some other css? Anyway the way you perform queries here `cmd = "Select * from dbo.ServiceRunningStatus where ServerName IN ('"+Server_list+"')"` you are **vulnerable** to **SQL Injection**.

Comment: yeah @AbdulAzizBarkat , the div is hidden , only first table will be displayed when table gets loaded and on click on a checkbox it will replace the first table div with second table div , it's actually toggle of first table div with second table div on a checkbox switch click .